# I set head to be something but it is always null

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement, struct

I am simply just trying to print out my doubly linked list. However, even though I clearly set my head and tail to something, it is always NULL when I print it in main. I am unsure on what the issue is. I've tried to simplify the code as much as I can.

In the function `grade_word_gen` you can clearly see I set head to something and I set tail to something.

test.txt

```
*A*
Great
Fantastic
Lovely
*B*
Bad
Not Good
Terrible
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct grade {
    struct grade_word *A_head;
    struct grade_word *A_tail;

    struct grade_word *B_head;
    struct grade_word *B_tail;

};

struct grade_word {
    char *word;
    struct grade_word *next;
    struct grade_word *prev;
};

struct grade *create_grade() {

    struct grade *new_grade = malloc(sizeof(struct grade));

    // Check grade was allocated correctly
    if (new_grade == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not allocate memory for grade\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Initialise all variables
    new_grade->A_head = NULL;
    new_grade->A_tail = NULL;

    new_grade->B_head = NULL;
    new_grade->B_tail = NULL;

    return new_grade;
}

struct grade_word *create_grade_word(char *word) {

    struct grade_word *new = malloc(sizeof(struct grade_word));

    if (new == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to allocate memory for grade_words\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Initialise vairables
    int len = strlen(word);
    new->word = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
    strcpy(new->word, word);
    new->next = NULL;
    new->prev = NULL;

    return new;
}

void grade_word_gen(struct grade *grade_data) {

    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    char grade;
    char buf[100 + 1];

    struct grade_word *new_node;
    struct grade_word *head;
    struct grade_word *tail;

    while (fgets(buf, 100, fp) != NULL) {

        if (buf[0] == '*' && buf[2] == '*') {
            grade = buf[1];

        } else {

            new_node = create_grade_word(buf);

            // Set next, prev, head, tail pointers
            if (grade == 'A') {
                head = grade_data->A_head;
                tail = grade_data->A_tail;
            } else {
                head = grade_data->B_head;
                tail = grade_data->B_tail;
            }

            // If first item set the head
            if (head == NULL) {
                head = new_node;
                //printf("head: %s\n", head->word);
            // Otherwise just add on to the list
            } else {
                new_node->prev = tail;
                tail->next = new_node;
            }

            tail = new_node;
        }
        // Reset buffer
        strcpy(buf, "\0");
    }

}

void print_grade_list(struct grade_word *list, char grade) {

    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("Grade %c is empty, so not grade words can be printed\n", grade);
        return;
    }

    printf("Grade: %c\n", grade);
    while (list != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", list->word);
        list = list->next;
    }
}

int main(void) {

    struct grade *new_grade = create_grade();

    grade_word_gen(new_grade);

    print_grade_list(new_grade->A_head, 'A');
    print_grade_list(new_grade->B_head, 'B');
}
```

My output is always `Grade %c is empty, so not grade words can be printed`. I don't understand why my head is always null, even though I do set it.

Comment: Not the problem, but you don't need the `+ 1` here `char buf[100 + 1];` if you use `fgets(buf, 100, fp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assign anything to `A_head` except in the initialization part where you assign NULL. Consequently `A_head` will remain at NULL:

The problem is here:

```
        if (grade == 'A') {
            head = grade_data->A_head;  // Here you make head equal A_head
            tail = grade_data->A_tail;
        } else {
            head = grade_data->B_head;
            tail = grade_data->B_tail;
        }

        // If first item set the head
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = new_node;     // Here you try to save new_node.
                                 // But you save it into head and that will not
                                 // change A_head
```

You need to have code like:

```
grade_data->A_head = new_node;
```

so that you actually change `A_head`.

An alternative way so that you can share the code between case A and B is double pointers. Like:

```
// Make a double pointer
struct grade_word **head;
. . .

// Make it point to either the A or B head pointer
head = &grade_data->A_head; // or head = &grade_data->B_head;
. . .

// Change A or B head pointer using head
*head = new_node;
```

Comment: My actual code has put this if statement in a function. And it returns the pointer to the head. I don't want t make all my if statements have `grade_data->A_head = new_node` because it will essentially duplicate the code over and over

Comment: @CoolGuy But grade is initialized? I set everything to null

Comment: @CoolGuy I made an assumption that There are only 2 grades. `A` and `B`

Comment: I also made the assumption that this function is called once only

Comment: @Kiwa Sorry, I missed the `test.txt` contents you provided

Comment: @CoolGuy That's fine. So if I parse a pointer to `head` variable. How can I make head change `grade_data->A_head` because I actually have 5 grades in my actual code. It means I will have to copy the grade code over and over. Like `grade_data->A_head = new_node` `grade_data->B_head = new_node` `grade_data->C_head = new_node` `grade_data->D_head = new_node` etc